# How to upload a zip file as a Static Resource via Migration Tool

Tags: force.com, static-resources, migration-tool

Problem:

I am trying to upload a zip file that contains js files, images, etc. as a Static Resource so that I can reference it in a VF page. I am able to successfully deploy the file using the Ant Migration Tool. However, when I check the resource on force.com, it is empty. This is true regardless of the file type that I have tried (txt, jpg, xml).

Project structure:

I currently have my build and src folders at the same level. Within the build folder I have build.xml and ant-salesforce.jar. Within my src folder I have package.xml and staticresources folder, within which I have the resource (test.resource) and the descriptor file (test.resource-meta.xml).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have been solved it?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps would lead you to success in this question

- Upload desired static resource to organization by means of **Develop -> Static resources -> New** with name, for example **TestResource**
- Add static resource to `package.xml`

  `<types>
      <members>TestResource</members>
      <name>StaticResource</name>
  </types>`
- Retrieve metadata mentioned in `package.xml` from organization.
- Voila! you have valid `TestResource.resource` and `TestResource.resource-meta.xml` in `staticresources` folder.

To read more about static resources and metadata refer to [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_staticresource.htm)

Comment: Thanks for responding! I already have it set up like that And I'm actually trying to deploy rather than retrieve. I have already been able to retrieve data correctly, but I was hoping to be able to deploy a zip via terminal rather than manually creating a new Static Resource on force.com. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I mentioned step, that you need to upload static resource first, because content of static resource is encoded to `base64Binary` field type. The static resource content. Base 64-encoded binary data. Prior to making an API call, client applications must encode the binary attachment data as base64. Upon receiving a response, client applications must decode the base64 data to binary. This conversion is usually handled for you by a SOAP client. So you have two options: manually convert `.zip` file to  `base64Binary` type, or let it to do for SF.

Comment: You fore sure have your own SF org for your own develop/test purposes. Upload desired zip resource to your own org, retrieve resource from there and then deploy it to originally desired SF organization.

Answer (score 0):

The test.resource file should be the zip file. Generically speaking, you would do something like this:

```
$ zip -r src/staticresources/test.resource build/resources/*
```

The test.resource file should be the ZIP file in question, and the test.resource-meta.xml should be the metadata for the file.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I already renamed my zip file (previously test.zip) to test.resource. But it still doesn't upload any actual content. It also will occasionally give me "Error: The specified static resource is not a valid zip file", but other times will deploy successfully, just with no content.

Comment: I too am getting the error message when trying to upload my Ubuntu generated zip File:
 "Error: The specified Static Resource is not a valid zip file"

My Zip command was run from my .../servedcontent/ folder:
zip -r bootstrap-4.0.0-dist.zip bootstrap-4.0.0-dist

I ran the upload again, it worked just fine.